# Macbook 6,2 webcam

Tags: 14.04, macbook

I had an issue with my Air, the integrated webcam could not be found. I fixed the issue with this package https://github.com/patjak/bcwc_pcie and it all was fine and flowers, but it once I restart my machine, the issue comes back, and I have to run the script again to make it work. Does anyone know how to make it stick ? Any help would be much appreciated. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Are you using this script?

https://github.com/patjak/bcwc_pcie/wiki/Get-Started#get-started-on-ubuntu

If so, I think that you just need to make the modprobe permanent

```
sudo modprobe -r bdc_pci
sudo modprobe facetimehd
```

In particular:

1. Use the blacklist to remove `bdc_pci` permanently
   /etc/modprobe.d/blacklist.conf
2. Create a new file (e.g. /etc/modprobe.d/facetimehd.conf) to load the facetimehd module

More info:
https://github.com/patjak/bcwc_pcie/issues/40#issuecomment-172527211